# "Sudden Death" function loops more than once before actually doing anything

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

having a bit of trouble with a function and a loop in my code. Basically the issue is that the "suddendeath" function should only run once and finish the game. However it loops about 3-5 times and then finishes the game.

Here is the pastebin link for the full code: http://pastebin.com/zTv35W8N

However, this is the function causing the issue:

```
def suddendeath():
    global charone_strength
    global chartwo_strength
    print "\n============"
    print "SUDDEN DEATH"
    print "============"
    time.sleep(1)
    player1 = random.randint(1,6)
    player2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print "\n"+str(charone)+" has rolled:",player1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "\n"+str(chartwo)+" has rolled:",player2
    if player1 == player2:
        print "\nIt's a draw!"
        suddendeath()
    if player1 > player2:
        chartwo_strength = 0
    elif player2 > player1:
        charone_strength = 0
```

And here is the loop:

```
while charone_strength > 0 or chartwo_strength > 0:
    if counter == 220:
        print "\nRound 220 has been reached, Sudden Death Mode active!"
        suddendeath()
    else:
        mods()
        battle(charone_strength, chartwo_strength, charone_skill, chartwo_skill, strength_mod, skill_mod)
else:
    if charone_strength <= 0:
        print "\n"+str(charone)+" has died!",chartwo,"wins!"
        time.sleep(1)
    elif chartwo_strength <= 0:
        print "\n"+str(chartwo)+" has died!",charone,"wins!"
        time.sleep(1)
    play = raw_input("Would you like to play again? y/n: ")
    if play in ["yes","y","Yes","Y"]:
        execfile("gcse.py")
    else:
        print "Goodbye! Thanks for playing!"
        exit()
```

I do advise reading the full code first, but any insight and further help would be appreciated on solving this issue. Cheers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `suddendeath` is supposed to finish the game, you should exit the loop after it executes, e.g.:

```
...
if counter == 220:
    print "\nRound 220 has been reached, Sudden Death Mode active!"
    suddendeath()
    break
```

Now the problem is that the `else` part of the `while` loop will not be executed if `break` occurs. As far as I understand, this code should be executed in any case, so just write it after the `while` without an `else`.

P.S. There are other problems, like `counter` not being defined or updated anywhere, but I guess it's because you did not post the full working code.

**Edit:** Disregard this answer, just leaving it for history. The real problem seems to be in the condition

```
while charone_strength > 0 or chartwo_strength > 0:
```

which should be

```
while charone_strength > 0 and chartwo_strength > 0:
```

So that the game ends if *one* of the players reaches strength `0` and not *both* of them.

Comment: There is a pastebin link to the code I currently have so far^^

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that.

Comment: What is meant to happen is that once the counter reaches 220, the loop will recognise it through the if statement, execute the function and then change the "strength" of the player who lost the dice roll to 0. It should then run the loop again and instead, run the code in the else at the bottom where it has 2 nested if statments in that case, finishing the game.

Comment: It has worked! Turns out the issue really was the loop's condition. Help appreciated, thanks:)!